# роутинг в nodejs(express)

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js, express

Задача реализовать роутинг на express используя базу из mysql.
Есть три страницы: главная, кафедра, преподаватели.
На главной ссылка переход на страницу кафедры, где в таблице указаны id и названия кафедры, у каждой кафедры есть ссылка при перехде по которой поподаем на страницу преподавателей, и вот тут начинаются сложности,никак не пойму что делать, при переходе по ссылке кафедр наужно показать преподавателей которые преподоют в соответствующей кафедре и на url строке показать kafedra/prepod/х где х является id кафедры

вот мой код:

```js
//app.js
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

var mysql = require('mysql');

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "root",
  password: "",
  database:'institut'
});

connection.connect();
app.use(express.static('public'))
 app.set('view engine', 'ejs')
 app.set('views','pages')
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.render('main')
})

app.get('/kafedra',(req,res)=>{
    connection.query('select*from detales join kafedra on detales.kafedra_id=kafedra',(err,data)=>{
        res.render('kafedra',{data})        
        console.log(data);
        
    })
})

app.get("/kafedra/prepodavateli/:id",(req,res)=>{
let id= req.params.id
         res.render('prepodavateli')
})
 
app.listen(3000,()=>{
    console.log('server started');
})
```

```html
<!--kafedra.ejs-->
<table class="table table-dark">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>id</th>
        <th>name</th>
        <th>actions</th>
       </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <% datas.forEach(item=>{ %>
    <tr>
        <td><%= item.id %></td>
        <td><%= item.name %></td>
        <td><a href="/kafedra/prepodavateli">prepodavateli</a></td>
      </tr> 
  <%  }) %>
      
     </tbody>
  </table>
  
  <!--prepodavateli.ejs-->
```

это база:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

добавьте в путь параметер который вы ждете на сервере

```
<td><a href="/kafedra/prepodavateli/%= item.id %">prepodavateli</a></td>
```